# Adb has stopped working suddenly

Tags: android, adb

Suddenly my `adb` is not working. I tried reinstalling sdk but it is still not working. Though android studio is working just fine.

[image]

Comment: Any reason for downvote ?

Comment: Did you solve this - I'm getting it now for no good reason :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get to the right location and try again!

In my case adb in located here:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Or maybe it's just a usual problem with your Windows

**Probably Windows issue: Try the following**

> Go to Control Panel, choose System and click **Advanced System settings**
>
> On the pop-up box -> select Advanced ->Click Settings under performance
>
> Another dialog appears -> Select Data Execution Prevention and **click add**
>
> Go to your **adb.exe** file and select it and **click apply and then OK**.
>
> You are done.!

Comment: It is already in the right location. I tried from the location itself

Comment: Goto File> Invalidate Caches and restart.. in android studio

Comment: Android studio is running just fine. It just that it is not working from CLI

Comment: Java (TM) platform SE binary -> End Process from the Task Manager, if that doesn't work restart your pc, if that doesn't work you know what to do next

Comment: Tried everything but still not working

Comment: try the edited and updated answer...this should be working

Comment: Still not working. I added adb in DEP and restarted my PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97185/discussion-between-johnrao07-and-mjosh).

Answer (score 9):

close your running **`adb.exe`** from task manager and **restart** **`adb.exe`** from platform.-tools 
[image]

Comment: Already did that. Not working

Comment: Still no luck with that. Adb is working when clicking on the adb.exe but when try comands like `adb devices` it is crashing.