# Adb.exe stopped when exiting adb shell

Tags: android, adb, android-studio-2.3

I'm using android studio 2.3.3. my emulator is Nexus 7 with API 25. My question is when i want to exit from adb shell, why the adb.exe always stopped working?

[image]

Comment: what is your laptop's(or machine's) configuration?

Comment: my pc: RAM 8 GB, i3 windows 10 pro 64bit  
my emulator: RAM 1GB, VM heap 80 MB ,internal 800MB

Comment: Try installing this driver: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/adb-fb-apx-driver-universal-naked-t1996051...using `pnputil -i -a nameoffile.inf`

Comment: can you give me the installation step?

Comment: You can do one more thing. You could look up:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130664/adb-has-stopped-working-suddenly

Comment: nothing works for me. and for the video i think its for device but i'm using android studio emulator